# List null android

Tags: android, lista

Estou com problema na lista, no metodo `init()` que é acionado assim que entro na tela tem o seguinte código:

```
listaOpcionais = Globales.getListaOpcionais();
```

Neste momento seto a minha lista o que tem em globales, porém a primeira vez que inicializo a tela, ela seta a minha lista ao valor `null` isto me da problemas quando por exemplo vou adicionar um item:

```
listaOpcionais.add(opcao);
```

Como faço para neste momento seta uma lista vazia, caso retorne `null` ? Em minha classe `Globales` estou setando assim:

```
private static List<OpcaoPedido> listaOpcionais;

public static List<OpcaoPedido> getListaOpcionais() {
    return listaOpcionais;
}

public static void setListaOpcionais(List<OpcaoPedido> listaOpcionais) {
    Globales.listaOpcionais = listaOpcionais;
}
```

E em minha classe inicializo assim:

```
List<OpcaoPedido> listaOpcionais = new ArrayList<OpcaoPedido>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar que retorne null, verifique se a lista não foi instanciada.

```
public static List<OpcaoPedido> getListaOpcionais() {
 if(listaOpcionais == null){
     return new ArrayList<OpcaoPedido>();
 }
     return listaOpcionais; 
 }
```

Comment: Isto coloco em minha classe globales?

Comment: Substitui seu método 
public static List<OpcaoPedido> getListaOpcionais() {
    return listaOpcionais;
}